# PHP PayPal Express Checkout IPN Not Completing Sale (Pics)

Tags: php, paypal

I am having trouble getting a transaction to complete using the PayPal Express Checkout IPN. Right now I am testing everything in Sandbox mode.

Using `SetExpressCheckout`, I am able to generate a token and am being redirected to the first payment page:

[image: First Page]

When I enter my login information, I am prompted to click the button to continue towards confirming the payment:

[image: Second]

When I click Continue on that page, I am then redirected back to the first page. It is just an endless loop of these two pages.

My login information is correct and the sandbox account has enough funds in it to complete the sale. All of the buyer and purchase information is being sent correctly. I just can't figure out why I can't get past this step.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can send the Correlation ID and ask PayPal what's wrong.

Comment: @KenCheung - Can you please tell me what the Correlation ID is and how I obtain it?

Comment: You use EC IPN, i.e. SetExpressCheckout, GetExpressCheckoutDetails, and DoExpressCheckoutPayment. For any one of these IPN you will also receive a Correlation ID and this ID is the one used to communicate with PayPal, and the documentation also told us to keep the Correlation ID for all calls to PayPal. For example in SetExpressCheckout you receives Timestamp, Correlation ID, Acknowledge, and EC Token. Check it out!

Comment: It sounds like you don't have your calls setup correctly.  Are you calling GetExpressCheckoutDetails and DoExpressCheckoutPayment in your ReturnURL?  Sounds like you're just calling SetExpressCheckout again and redirecting right back to PayPal..??  No IPN will be triggered until the final DoExpressCheckoutPayment call is made which processes the actual payment.